# Group datetime series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame where the the columns are “city” and “datetime”. The data indicates the arrival of VIP’s into the city.

```
City      datetime
New York  2022-12-06 10:37:25
New York  2022-12-06 10:42:34
New York  2022-12-06 10:47:12
New York  2022-12-06 10:52:10
New York  2022-12-06 02:37:25
```

As you can see the last column stands out from the rest as datetime. The first 3 entries are at a time interval less than 10minutes with respect to the column above and the last column datetime Interval is more than 10minutes.

Now I want to group city into 2 different groups , the first 3 as 1 group and last column alone as 1 group.

Desired out out

```
City     datetime- count
New York   4 [‘2022-12-06 10:37:25’,  2022-12-06 10:42:34’, ‘2022-12-06 10:47:12’, ‘2022-12-06 10:52:10’]
New York   1 [‘2022-12-06 02:37:25’]
```

This is my first time using this forum . Any help is greatly appreciated

I have tried groupby on the ”city” column but it just group every column with the same city name . But I want to group the city based date time.

Comment: What is your metric for "way far off"? And what is your expected output? Please edit your post to contain these two things.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Very much appreciate your prompt response. I have made the changes to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `groupby` with `Grouper`:

```py
# create df
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York'],
    'datetime': ['2022-12-06 10:37:25', '2022-12-06 10:42:34', '2022-12-06 10:47:12', '2022-12-06 10:52:10',
                 '2022-12-06 02:37:25']
})

# set datetime col as index
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df['Date'] = df.index

# groupby
grouped = df.groupby(['City', pd.Grouper(freq='15min', origin='start')])
new_df = grouped.count()
new_df['Dates'] = grouped['Date'].apply(list)
new_df.reset_index().drop('datetime', axis=1)
```

output:

[image: output]

Learn more: [pandas.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I am getting the error “‘DataframeGroupBy’ object has no attribute ‘value_counts’”

Comment: You can use `size` instead of `value_counts`. please let me know if it works. @StarLord

Comment: It doesn’t work and also the output you got is not the one I want. Please see the expected output above. Thanks

Comment: Basically I want to aggregate the date time column

Comment: both versions work for me (with `value_counts` or `size`). what's your pandas version?
actually I think the output is ok. the time diff is more than 10min for row 3 against row 0. if you want you can set the `freq` to `'15min'`

Comment: Yes, this is an aggregation over datetime, because I set the datetime as index, and pandas Grouper aggregates over the index

Comment: @Hamidi Rasti is it possible to check the frequency for column right above each time . Like you said the time interval between row 3 and row 0 is more than 10 minutes but the time interval between  row 3 and row 2 is less than 10 minutes. Thanks

Comment: @StarLord Do you need the time diff between each row and its previous row?

Comment: yes that exactly what I need I guess. So that I can group all the rows where the time difference is less than 10mins

Comment: Hey I deleted the comment intentionally but the accepted mark was an error . My apologies

Comment: calculate time diff: `df['TimeDiff'] = df.datetime - df.datetime.shift(1)`

Comment: chek if less than 10min: `df['TimeDiff'] < pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)`

Comment: after you created the `df` do the 2 lines above. is it what you wanted? @StarLord

Comment: I added both the lines after creating df but I am getting unsupported error , can you just change the code in your answer so that it will be easy for me . THANKS IN ADVANCE 

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Same as the original output. But irrespective of the start time , I want all the rows grouped if the time difference row and previous row is less than 10 minutes.

Comment: In your answer I got desired output but instead of increasing the frequency to 15mins I want to group all the rows if the time difference is less than 10mins. Once again my apologies if I am being unclear.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch it :) You can change the `freq` to `10min`. and then you will have 3 clusters with this input data. You cannot have a dynamic time `freq`!

Comment: Considering the answer I am looking for is deviating from the original question , I have posted another question and explained everything in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74702759/group-datetime-column-based-on-the-time-difference